# How to set web grid page button count in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I have defined a webgrid as such:

```
@{

ViewBag.Title = "WebGrid";
var grid = new WebGrid(null,
    defaultSort: ViewBag.sortCol,
    sortFieldName: "sortCol",
    sortDirectionFieldName: "sortDir",
    rowsPerPage: ViewBag.rowsPerPage);
grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: ViewBag.count, autoSortAndPage: false);

}
```

I'm not sure how to set the property `PageButtonCount`for the webgrid in MVC 5

Comment: have you tried a google search for `C# MVC how to set PageButtonCount`

Comment: Yes but most of the stuff is for older versions of MVC and when ever I try to implement, VS can't recognise PageButtonCount